# Where to put META-INF folder for JPA application

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans

The title pretty much sums it up, where would I put the META-INF directory, this is the directory that needs to include the persistence.xml file. My first guess is in the root of my application as a sibling folder of "Source Packages". Thanks in advance! PS - Using a Maven project structure...

Screenshot of my current setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `META-INF` folder needs to be placed at the root of the classpath, this can be achieved by placing it as a direct child of a source folder.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, if you look at my edited question you'll see I've attached a screenshot of my current project setup. When looking at that where would you place the META-INF folder?

Comment: Under source packages, when the application is built the META-INF directory should find its way to the `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` directory.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your managed classes are. In an EAR, you would probably put it into the root of the domain JAR. In a web application (WAR), a common location is the `WEB-INF/classes` folder, so your final structure would look like this:

`WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml`

This is convenient, since all your classes would be processed by the persistence provider.

Comment: In this instance all my classes are in Project-Root / Source Packages / com.deangrobler.test / [classes.java] .. I'll edit my question with a screenshot quick..

Answer (score 0):

Is your projected structured as shown on [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Configuration files (like hibernate.xml) should be placed in /src/main/resources
In the "packaging" stage of maven, the files will automatically be placed in the correct META-INF directory